# How can I select an image in a directory by its name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've made an image upload feature in my MVC Application.  The image is uploaded into a directory within the application and resized, renamed and formatted using ImageResizer plugin.  All images are renamed to ID numbers.

What I would like to know is, once the image is in the directory is there a way to select an image by it's name? I've tried a few different ways but I can't get anything to work.

Here is the code that I attempted to use with a 'where' statement but this approach didn't work.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? vesselId)
{
    var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/vessels/");
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
    var model = new VesselImagesViewModel
    {
          VesselImages = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath)
            .Select(fn => Path.GetFileName(fn))
            .Where(fileName.Equals(vesselId));
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what do you mean by select image by its name?

Comment: WHere do you stuck on? The error message? What happenned?

Comment: `public ActionResult Details(string name) { return File(Path.Combine(..., name)); }`?

Comment: The images are all renamed to id numbers so I want to return an image by a specified ID for example 47.

Comment: `VesselImages = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath).Where(id=>Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(id) == vesselId.ToString()).Select(fn => "~/Content/images/vessels/" + Path.GetFileName(fn))`. Here I'm using [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare the filename without extension to the id as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Quantic for the input into this, by comparing the filename with:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
```

The full code is as follows:

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? vesselId)
    {
        //
        // Enumerate through the images directory and
        //return the results to the view.
        var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/vessels/");
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

        var model = new VesselImagesViewModel
        {
            VesselImages = Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath)
            .Select(fn => "~/Content/images/vessels/" + Path.GetFileName(fn))
            .Where(id => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(id) == vesselId.ToString())
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```